# Issue with Cisco ASA IPSec VPN clients can't access DMZ network

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, ipsec

I have one ASA that is configured for IPSec VPN Cisco client. The VPN allow access to inside network, but trying to get it to my DMZ is a problem. My VPN address pool is defined as 124.140.1.x /24. My DMZ1 is defined as 192.168.44.x/24. After connecting to my VPN client, I can ping anything on the inside network, but I get the following when trying to ping a DMZ device:

[image]

I do have anti-spoofing on and I would like to keep it that way. Is seems that traffic is going one way and leaving another. ASA does not support that asymmetrical traffic.

My NAT rule is (dmz1) to (outside) source static DMZ1-Network DMZ1-Network destination static Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN no-proxy-arp route-lookup description For VPN to access DMZ1 translate_hits = 16, untranslate_hits = 16

I believe that this is right.

[image]

```
Config file:
```

```
ip local pool IPSEC-VPN-Pool 124.140.1.1-124.140.1.254 mask 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description Outside
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 mac-address 0019.0724.64f7
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ddns update DYNU
 dhcp client update dns
 ip address dhcp setroute 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0
 description Inside
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address Firewall 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1.100
 description DMZ1 for Duke Network
 vlan 100
 nameif dmz1
 security-level 50
 ip address 192.168.44.1 255.255.255.0 
!
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
object network DukeLAN
 subnet 144.244.244.0 255.255.255.0
 description Inside Network
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1
 network-object object DukeLAN
 network-object object DMZ1-Network
object-group service DM_INLINE_SERVICE_4
 service-object icmp timestamp-reply
 service-object icmp unreachable
 service-object tcp destination eq ssh 
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_2
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_3
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_4
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_5
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group network DM_INLINE_NETWORK_2
 network-object object DMZ1-Network
 network-object object DukeLAN
access-list 102 extended permit ip object DukeLAN object Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN 
access-list limit-torrent extended permit ip any4 object DellMedia_Upstairs 
access-list Split_Tunnel remark Duke Network
access-list Split_Tunnel standard permit 144.244.244.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list Split_Tunnel remark VPN
access-list Split_Tunnel standard permit 124.140.1.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list Split_Tunnel remark Duke DMZ
access-list Split_Tunnel standard permit 192.168.44.0 255.255.255.0 
access-list 101 extended permit ip object DukeLAN object Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN 
access-list Dmz1_Access_In remark DMZ can get access to Internet
access-list Dmz1_Access_In remark Anything in DMZ can get access to Internet
access-list Dmz1_Access_In remark Block DMZ to any where
access-list Dmz1_Access_In extended deny ip any any 
access-list outside_cryptomap_1.1_1 extended deny object-group VPN_Ports interface inside interface outside 
access-list outside_cryptomap_1.1_2 extended permit ip object Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_2 
access-list outside_cryptomap_65535.65535_1 extended permit ip object DukeLAN any inactive 
access-list outside_cryptomap_65535.65535_2 extended deny ip object DukeLAN any inactive 
access-list outside_cryptomap_65535.65535 extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_1 object DukeLAN any object-group TCP-UDP2049 
access-list inside_cryptomap_65535.65535 extended permit ip object DukeLAN object Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN 
access-list dmz1_cryptomap_65535.65535 extended permit ip object DMZ1-Network object Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN 
access-list inside_cryptomap_65535.65535_1 extended permit ip object DukeLAN object Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN 
access-list outside_cryptomap_10.10 extended permit ip object Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN object-group DM_INLINE_NETWORK_1 
access-list IPSecVPN_Policy remark Allow VPN users Internet and ICMP
access-list IPSecVPN_Policy extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_SERVICE_3 object Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN any 
no pager
nat (dmz1,outside) source static DMZ1-Network DMZ1-Network destination static Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN no-proxy-arp route-lookup description For VPN to access DMZ1
nat (dmz1,outside) source static MarksPlex interface service 32400_in 32400_out description For Outside Access to Plex
nat (inside,dmz1) source static DMZ1-Network interface service 37777 37777 description To allow traffic to flow from a lower security level (DMZ). So it can reach DukeDVR in a higher security (Inside)
nat (outside,inside) source static any any destination static DukeDVR DukeDVR service 37777 37777 description For Outside access to DVR
nat (inside,outside) source dynamic DukeLAN interface description Allow Inside Access to the Outside
nat (inside,outside) source static DukeLAN DukeLAN destination static Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN route-lookup description For Inside VPN Split tunnel
!
object network DukeLAN
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface dns
object network obj_any
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
!
nat (dmz1,outside) after-auto source dynamic any interface
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
access-group inside_access_in in interface inside
access-group Dmz1_Access_In in interface dmz1
group-policy "No Access" attributes
 vpn-simultaneous-logins 0
 vpn-filter value inside_access_in
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 
 address-pools value IPSEC-VPN-Pool
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
 dns-server value 4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8
 vpn-idle-timeout none
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 ikev2 ssl-client 
 ipsec-udp enable
 split-tunnel-policy excludespecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value Split_Tunnel
 default-domain value Duke.com
 address-pools value IPSEC-VPN-Pool
 webvpn
  anyconnect dpd-interval client none
  anyconnect dpd-interval gateway none
  hidden-shares visible
group-policy IPSEC-Remote-VPN internal
group-policy IPSEC-Remote-VPN attributes
 banner value Welcome to Duke Network. For offical use only!
 dns-server value 4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8
 vpn-simultaneous-logins 2
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value ACL-SPLIT-TUNNEL
 default-domain value Duke.com
 client-access-rule none
```

Can someone please tell me how to config this ASA so that I can access my VPN clients can access the DMZ1?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Why do you use public IP addresses that you don't own for a private VPN pool? At the very least, you need to fix the routing problem caused by that. Also, you should *never* use NAT within your private network.

Comment: Yes, you need to change your VPN pool addresses to be a non-public IP address network so they don't have routing conflicts. That will certainly help.

Comment: I don't think that the issue. I've been using that IP address for a long time and it's been working, allowing me to access the inside with no issues. The VPN pool addresses are created only when the VPN client connects. The ASA creates a static route to the outside interface.

Comment: A few major things: (1) Your packet-tracer output is untrustworthy because the ASA does not permit you to specify whether your simulated packet arrived through a tunnel. Therefore, the result is not what the ASA would actually do. (2) It appears that you redacted the `route` statements from your config. You're almost certainly dealing with a route problem (RPF), so it'd be nice to see those statements. (3) Your Split-Tunnel config is jacked up. Your `DfltGrpPolicy` is set to exclude those ranges, while the more-specific `IPSEC-Remote-VPN` policy is referencing an ACL that doesn't exist.

Comment: A few minor things: (1) What is the content of object `DMZ1-Network`? (2) What is the content of object `Obj-Remote-IPSEC-VPN`?